# Scope User.Read.All not works for azure b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-oauth2

I am able to get access token using custom scope user_impersonation.

```
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
p=B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN&
client_id=IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId&
nonce=defaultNonce&
redirect_uri=xxx&
scope="https://xx.onmicrosoft.com/xx/user_impersonation"&
response_type=token&
prompt=login
```

If I change it to User.Read.All  I'll got error

> This+application+does+not+have+sufficient+permissions+against+this+web+resource+to+perform+the+operation

Below my scope settings. I am trying to read users profile to get email.

[image]
How to read users profile data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added below **API permissions** to the Azure AD B2C Application:

[image]

I generated the **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/user_impersonation
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I tried to fetch user's details using the access token, **I got the similar error** like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

[image]

The error "***This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation***" usually occurs if the access token doesn't have the sufficient permissions to perform the action.

> **Note** that: To access the user profiles, you need to grant `User.Read.All` Microsoft Graph API permission not custom scope.

The **`aud`** of the access token when decoded must be Microsoft Graph not the ClientID of the Application.

Azure AD B2C supports only **`offline_access`** and **`openid`** Microsoft Graph delegated API permissions.

- Don't generate tokens for the Microsoft Graph API using user flows or custom policies, these can only be used to obtain tokens for web APIs, not the Microsoft Graph APIs.
- To obtain Microsoft Graph API tokens for Azure AD B2C tenant, use the authentication flow (*auth code flow or ROPC flow*) that is specific to Azure AD.

I added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

I used the below **authorize** endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated the **access token**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

***I am able to fetch the user's successfully like below:***

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Graph API and B2C - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1085094/graph-api-and-b2c) by CarlZhao-MSFT